# Registering Servlet on a Specified Port

Tags: java, servlets, osgi

I want to register a ServLet on a specified port, because my port 80 using by another programs that i need them and i can close and kill them.
This is my code for registering servlet :

```
 HttpService httpService = (HttpService) super.addingService(reference);
                if (httpService == null)
                        return null;

                try {
                        System.out.println("Registering servlet at /simple");
                        httpService.registerServlet("/simple", new SimpleServlet(), null,
                                        null);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

Comment: AFAIK, you can't register the port of a servlet.  The port is assigned to the application (i.e. app server).  Unless OSGI kicks of a new server with the port, you'll have to configure this on the app server.

Answer (score 1):

You can definitely only set the port of the HttpService itself, but it will never try to use port 80 by default. Would it be an idea to configure the server you've got at 80 to proxy certain parts to the OSGi service?

This stuff is a bit trickier than it seems. Getting all the web stuff working (especially more advanced stuff like Filters) isn't that easy.

Pax Web made it much easier. ([this bundle](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.ops4j.pax.web%7Cpax-web-jetty-bundle%7C3.0.4%7Cbundle) contains Jetty and all its dependencies, so you can remove the jetty you are using now)

The port can be configured using OSGi configuration, but by default it is on 8080.

Comment: With pax web it's even possible to bind your application (not servlet) to a "virtual host"  specific port.

Answer (score 0):

No, this can only be done at container level. Which is your application server? For tomcat, check out the port parameter of the [HTTP connector](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/http.html).

Comment: When i execute this code , the servlet registered with out error, but my port 80 is using by another program.is it possible to the servlet registered on another port automatically?if yes, how should i know the port number?

Comment: It will in one of your app server's config files. In tomcat, it will be server.xml.

Comment: I don't know what is my app server.i just download osgi plug-in and use it in eclipse on windows.

Comment: I think its a build in jetty server which is shipped with the osgi plugin. Its better to download tomcat. Register it as a web-server within Eclipse Server Options and deploy your web app (servlet) within that server. After that you can do the configurations within Tomcat like already mentioned above

Comment: @ChristianSchack Yes , it useing jetty server.i have to configure this project on jetty server.what should i do?

Comment: Whats the name of the plugin. I also have to look. I think there are preferences for this plugin where you can configure jetty bootstrap. Or you can add jetty parameters via the run dialog.

Comment: You mentioned there is a another service running on port 80 on you maschine. Must be a web server. Apache, Microsoft Webserver IIS or whatever. Maybe you can turn these services of during deveolopment of you app. Don't know !